# Modify an HTML value with JS variable

Tags: javascript, html, tags

I have this function, that takes the value of "count", prints it and save it in a variable

```
<input type="number" id="count" min="1" value="1" style="text-align:center"><br><br>
        <script>

            $('#count').bind('click keyup', function(){
               alert($(this).val());
               $hello = $(this).val();
            });
        </script>
```

and i want to take $hello and put it in a value in a input tag, something like this

```
<input name="x" type="hidden" value="//here would be $hello">
```

How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,it will work

```
 $('#count').bind('click keyup', function(){
                   alert($(this).val());
                   var hello = $(this).val();
                   $("#check").val(hello);   
                });

    <input name="x" id="check" type="hidden" value="//here would be hello">
```

Comment: @Hook thank u..accept the answer it will be useful for others

Answer (score 2):

jQuery's [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) method is both a getter and a setter.

Try this:

`$('input[name="x"]').val($hello);`

Answer (score 1):

User setter variable after $hello

```
     <input type="number" id="count" min="1" value="1" style="text-align:center"><br><br>
            <script>

                $('#count').bind('click keyup', function(){
                   alert($(this).val());
                   $hello = $(this).val();
$("#x").val($hello);
                });
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery `val()` method is used to apply the value to input element:

```
<input type="number" id="count" min="1" value="1" style="text-align:center"><br><br>
<input name="x" type="hidden" value="//here would be $hello">
        <script>

            $('#count').bind('click keyup', function(){
               alert($(this).val());
               $hello = $(this).val();
               $('input[name="x"]').val($hello);

            });
        </script>
```

[demo link](https://jsfiddle.net/5uTFE/2/)